# Programmatically determine if "enable access for assistive devices" is checked in Cocoa app

Tags: cocoa, accessibility

Cocoa apps using the NSAccessibility API require "enable access for assistive devices" to be checked in the Universal Access pref pane. I've seen many apps pop a warning if this is disabled when they run. How do I programmatically check if this is enabled so I can show a warning in my app?

Comment: Once you are able to detect that the setting has been turned on, how do you begin using the Assistive Access? Is an app restart required?

Comment: Asked that question here, looks like you do need a restart: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9132845/how-do-i-give-my-app-assistive-access-privileges-once-enable-access-for-assis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for `AXAPIEnabled()`.

```
extern Boolean AXAPIEnabled ();
```

Quoting [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accessibility/Reference/AccessibilityLowlevel/AXUIElement_h/CompositePage.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AXAPIEnabled):

> Returns whether the accessibility API is enabled.
>
> Returns TRUE if the accessibility API is currently enabled, otherwise
> FALSE.
>
> Assistive applications will not work if the accessibility API is not
> enabled or if the calling process is not a trusted accessibility
> client. Users can enable the accessibility API by checking "Enable
> access for assistive devices" in Universal Access Preferences.

Comment: You should also read the [AXIsProcessTrusted / AXMakeProcessTrusted](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/135734-axisprocesstrusted-axmakeprocesstrusted.html) discussion. You'll learn that you should also check for `AXIsProcessTrusted()`.

Comment: `AXAPIEnabled()` has been deprecated in OS X 10.9 Mavericks

Comment: Yes, for this functionality in 10.9, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17693408/enable-access-for-assistive-devices-programmatically-on-10-9) and its most highly rated answer.

Answer (score 21):

In OS X 10.9 Mavericks, `AXAPIEnabled()` [has been deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ApplicationServices/Reference/AXUIElement_header_reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AXAPIEnabled).

`AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions` can be used instead:

```
NSDictionary *options = @{(id)kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt: @YES};
BOOL accessibilityEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions((CFDictionaryRef)options);
```

If you pass in `YES` for `kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt`, the system will show the user a helpful little dialog with a link to System Preferences:

> "YourApp.app would like to control this computer using accessibility features."

[image]