# How do I give my app "assistive access privileges" once "Enable Access for Assistive Devices" has been checked?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-carbon

I have an app that uses a (perfectly user-benevolent) system-wide keyboard hook for accessibility purposes.

When the app starts up, I check if the "Enable Access for Assistive Devices" setting is checked, as asked by someone else here: [Programmatically determine if "enable access for assistive devices" is checked in Cocoa app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6933510/programmatically-determine-if-enable-access-for-assistive-devices-is-checked-i)

My problem is that, even after Enabling Access via the checkbox, the app continues to run without those privileges. How do I give the (currently running) app the privileges and get the keyboard hook working? Do I need to restart the app?

Comment: Your app privs are probably set on startup, so yes, you probably have to restart your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the link you posted,

> I asked the Accessibility engineer again, and apparently you have to
>   re-exec or re-launch the now-trusted application for the new state to
>   take effect.

I would present the user with a notification or message that the application has to restart to enable assistive privileges, then restart it.

Comment: If this is a big problem, you could run the keyboard hook in a small, secondary executable (which could also live in the same bundle) which could be cycled if necessary by the primary app, and relay key-press notifications back to the main app via some other means.  But if you can just require a restart of the app, that'll be the simplest.